# Javascript class ajax callback this that

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Javascript**

```
var MyClass = function(){
    var that = this;
    this.bool = false;
}

MyClass.prototype.ajax = function(url, callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: callback
    });
}

MyClass.prototype.ajaxCall = function(){
    this.ajax("ajax.php", this.ajaxCallback);
}

MyClass.prototype.ajaxCallback = function(data){
    that.bool = true;
}
```

Now the problem is here

```
that.bool = true;
```

I made a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/J3P8t/

**Error** Uncaught ReferenceError: that is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get rid of `that` and do:

```
MyClass.prototype.ajaxCall = function(){
    this.ajax("", $.proxy(this.ajaxCallback, this)); //or this.ajaxCallback.bind(this)
}

MyClass.prototype.ajaxCallback = function(data){
    this.bool = true;
}
```

Or

```
MyClass.prototype.ajaxCall = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.ajax("your url", function(){
       self.ajaxCallback.apply(self, arguments);
    });
}

MyClass.prototype.ajaxCallback = function(data){
    console.log(data);
    this.bool = true;
}
```

`that` is a local variable created in the scope of `MyClass` constructor function which is not available outside. So accessing an undeclared variable throws an error. using [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) or [function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) you are binding a context to the function reference. SO using it in side the jq ajax call will set the context as that of the MyClass instance instead of jqxhr object.

Comment: So this is the only way ? Just feels pretty stupid that ajaxCallback is a MyClass function, but still unable to access it's variables.

Comment: Ok but still I'd need to pass reference to this. Thanks I'll just have to live with that :)

Comment: Hey, I managed to make a little simpler solution, cause I have many functions using the same ajax function call. Is there any problem with my approach to problem ?

Comment: Don't confuse JavaScript with a strongly-typed language... here, functions are first-class objects too, which means they can go anywhere and anybody can use them.  `this` can be a very tricky concept for JavaScript to figure out; try reading [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

Comment: @JoniSalmi Yes you could do that as well. But issue could be if you want to use another callback with another bound object or using a call/apply yours will overwrite it. So better you can use it at the caller.